# Numpy slice from beginning and from end

Tags: python, numpy

```
array = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
array[-1:3:1]
>> []
```

I want this array indexing to return something like this:

```
[10,1,2,3]
```

Comment: `np.roll` makes the job easy, but its code is rather complication - mostly because it can roll in more than one dimension as once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`np.roll`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) to:

> Roll array elements along a given axis. Elements that roll beyond the last position are re-introduced at the first.

```
>>> np.roll(x, 1)[:4]
array([10,  1,  2,  3])
```

Answer (score 4):

[np.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) lets you wrap an array which might be useful

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

b = np.roll(a,1)[0:4]
```

results in

```
>>> b
array([10  1  2  3])
```

Answer (score 3):

As one of the answers mentioned, rolling the array makes a copy of the whole array which can be memory consuming for large arrays. So just another way of doing this without converting to list is:

`np.concatenate([array[-1:],array[:3]])`

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.r_`:

```
import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> arr = np.arange(1, 11)
>>> arr[np.r_[-1:3]]
array([10,  1,  2,  3])
```

Comment: A more pythonic way might be `arr[range(-1,3)]`

Comment: @NightTrain Why? I personally do not find mixing numpy and pure python very elegant, in particular, indexing with range objects is notoriously slow. If you don't like `np.r_` (which is not the fastest itself) maybe `np.arange` could be acceptable to you?

Comment: sure `arr[np.arange(-1,3)]` would be more consistent. I'm preferring  `np.arange` over the builtin `range` anyway, since it supports floats. I just never used `np.r_` before and supposed I wasn't the only one.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution would be to convert first to list, and then join and return to array.

As such:

```
>>> numpy.array(list(array[-1:]) + list(array[:3]))
array([10,  1,  2,  3])
```

This way you can choose which indices to start and end, without creating a duplicate of the entire array